# Prove that if $R[x]$ finitely generated as $R$-module, then $R=\{0\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated

Let $R$ be commutative ring with 1. Prove that if $R[x]$ finitely generated as $R$-module, then $R=\{0\}$.

**Proof.**

$R[x]$ finitely generated as $R$-module imply for all $f(x)\in R[x]$ there exist $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n$ such that for some $f_1(x),f_2(x),\ldots,f_n(x)\in R[x]$,
$$f(x)=r_1f_1(x)+r_2f_2(x)+\ldots+r_nf_n(x).$$

But how to conclude $R=\{0\}$? I don't know to prove it. Any hint to prove it?

> I try proving contrapositive as below.
>
> If $R\neq\{0\}$, then $R[x]$ is not finitely generated as $R$-module.
>
> Take any $f(x)=r_0+r_1 x+r_2x^2+\ldots+r_nx^n\in R[x]$. Then there
> exist $r_0,r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n\in R$ and $1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n\in R[x]$
> (since $R\neq \{0\}$) such that  $$f(x)=r_0(1)+r_1
> > (x)+r_2(x^2)+\ldots+r_n(x^n).$$ Then we have the generating set for
> $R[x]$ is $$\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n\}.$$ I confused why the generating
> set is finite.

Comment: Hint: Try proving the contrapositive. That is, assume $R \neq \{ 0 \}$ and show that $R[x]$ cannot be finitely generated. You'll find, for instance, that $\{ x^i \}$ is an infinite algebraically independent set.

Comment: Generally, $f(x)\in R[x]$ is finite polynomial
($f(x)=r_0+r_1x+r_2x^2+\ldots+r_nx^n$)
 or infinite polynomial
($f(x)=r_0+r_1x+r_2x^2+\ldots$)
?

Comment: $R[x]$ consists of the "finite polynomials", though these are typically just called polynomials. When we want to consider a "polynomial" with infinitely many terms, we typically call them "power series" and we denote their ring by $R[[x]]$.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I have tried prove contrapositively. But I confused why the generating set is finite.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $R$ is not the zero ring and $R[x]$ is finitely generated by $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n$. We can clearly assume that none of the polynomials $f_i$ is zero, so all of them have a degree.

Let $k$ be the maximum degree of the generating polynomials. Now try to make
$$
x^{k+1}=r_1f_1+r_2f_2+\dots+r_nf_n \qquad (r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n\in R)
$$